# Allow only Google Workspace accounts with Google OAuth SSO

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using Google OAuth SSO to authenticate users to my website.

How do I show only Google Workspace (GSuite) accounts inside the Google "Choose an account" screen, instead of showing all Google accounts (gmail)?

Like the website https://www.g2.com/authorize did

Thanks,
Shahar

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

When redirecting the user to the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount url, you should add the query param hd=* and as a result Google would show only Google workspace accounts.
However, the user still can manually enter a gmail account.

Comment: Any detailed article or docs on this?